Updating Conda in Ubuntu results in endless circle
Basically some update broke anaconda on my Linux machine.
Any action with conda results in
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed
WARNING conda.exceptions:print_unexpected_error_report(1257): KeyError('pkgs_dirs')


Users are suggesting
CONDA_OVERRIDE_CUDA=10.2 conda install -n base -c conda-forge libffi

here:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11366
However, this just tells me that there is nothing to update and funnily enough also this:
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.14.0
  latest version: 24.7.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda



# All requested packages already installed.


So basically, can't update conda, can't update stuff that would let me update conda.
I am out of ideas. Does anyone have some?

What is it, anaconda (as in your text), or miniconda (which you have also tagged)?

It is miniconda

Can you please post the entire stack trace?  There is no way to know if this error is arising form cuda or something else entirely.
